# Outputting the last 6 digits using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to come up with a way using XSL to output the last 6 digits of the following field

```
<NameReference Text="4380.401.0500-111820" />
```

I wrote the following expression based on the xml file:

```
<xsl:if test="">
<xsl:for-each select="NameReference">
<ID>
<Data>
<xsl:value-of select="substring(@Text,-6)"/>
</Data>
</ID>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
```

However, the output was as follows “43804010500111820”. It basically parses the entire field as the desired data, where i am only looking for the last 6 digits after the dash '-' . I was trying to go from left to right, but that hasn’t worked. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2nd parameter to the `substring` function is the start position. You want to start taking characters from the `length-6` position.

Try

```
substring(@Text, string-length(@Text) - 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth knowing, for future reference, about the **substring-after** function. This would be of benefit to use if you had a variable number of digits after the hyphen. In this case you could do this:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@Text, '-')" />
```

That should also output `111820` in this case.